# What if someone makes a mistake reciting Surah fatiha in prayer?

Tags: salat, mistake, surat-al-fatihah

If while praying a person makes a mistake in Surah Fatiha and realizes his mistake after saying Ameen does he have to begin recitation again from the beginning or should he start from the Ayah that he got wrong? What about a person who makes this mistake behind an imam and has to hurry because the Imam has started bowing?

Comment: See also: "[Sujud Sahwi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sujud_Sahwi)". But, I think, asking for forgiveness after the Salah would suffice in your case (both whether behind Imam or not). Which sect do you belong to?

Comment: I don't belong to any. But you can say everyone around me follows Hanafi.

Answer (score 0):

May Allah forgive me if I am wrong, but I was brought up knowing that the imam is responsible for the recitations while in congregation.  You can recite El fatiha and other sura for yourself but this is not obligatory.

If you are performing salah by yourself, then just repeat the whole sura.

At the end of the salah, before you salut the angels on both sides, perform 2 more sajdas for repentance for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Assalaamu a'laykum wa ragmatullahie wabarakaatu!

I'm not learned. As far as my to my knowledge, surah faatiga is the only surah you have to recite otherwise your salaah null and void. You are allowed to make 3 mistakes more than that your salaah is null and void.

In congregation:
You recite after the Imam. He will be silent before he starts with the short surah and that is for you to recite surah faatiga. If you did not get to complete surah faatigah it's OK because you made niyyah Imaaman liellaahie ta a'lah.

It is no need to make the sujud of forgetfulness for surah faatigah though it is a fard requirement.

Jazaaqallaah min gheir!

Comment: The recitation of al-Fatihah is considered as fard by the majority of scholars, mistakes of fard acts can't be repaired .

Answer (score 0):

Asalamualikum,

1. Correct your mistakes in surah Fatiha and learn it well.
2. If you read the surah and the meaning completely changed then you have to repeat your prayer.
3. If you are praying behind the Imam, you can recite Surah Al- Fatiha or you can just listen to the Imam recite.

Reference: https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/83461/noticing-a-mistake-made-during-prayer-in-quran-recitation

Answer (score -1):

Wssalamualaikum wr wb, 
Allah knows best.

You should repeat from where you made mistake. I am still not sure that, one has to give prostration of forgetfulness or not for mistake in one verse/ anywhere in Al Fatiha, but it is the obligatory part of salah, that's why I personally give prostration of forgetfulness as a repentance.  I am still trying to correct my salah.

Allah knows best.